# Does the GC-Logic works in all Browsers the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, garbage-collection

I trying to understand a bit more about Garbage collection. I am currently using Google Chrome's Tools like Speed Tracer, Timeline and Profiles for our web app.

I made a simple test and counted all created dom elements on a single page with JQuery but the result is different in all browsers.

```
970 Dom elements in Chrome
967 Dom elements in Firefox
969 Dom elements in IE10

//The difference is not that big but I just wanted to know
```

After I saw that, I just wanted to ask if is there a difference between the browsers when GC called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely differences in the specific implementation of the garbage collection in different browsers, but the basic principles are the same.

The differences in the number of elements is more likely because of the differences in how the documents are parsed. Browsers doesn't only parse tags to elements, the text between elements are parsed into text nodes, and they also count as DOM elements. Some browsers create text nodes for spaces or line breaks between tags where other browsers don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is different.  All browsers have their own implementation of JavaScript and thus the GC and all other details of the implementation will be different.